# Однако и один: что между ними общего?

Tags: лексика

Один и однако ― **этимологически родственные слова, но разные по смыслу и грамматической роли**. 
Слово **однако** ― союз, вводное слово, междометие ― обозначает противопоставление, близко по значению к союзу НО, синонимично частицам с уступительным значением (всё-таки, тем не менее), а в качестве междометия может выражать удивление и возмущение.

Как все эти значения связаны со значением счетно-местоименного слова один?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения наслаивались постепенно.

ОДНАКО развилось из др.-рус. ОДЬНАКО - буквально "ОДИНОКО", "ОБОСОБЛЕННО", отсюда значение частицы "ТОЛЬКО", "ВСЁ-ТАКИ". После падения редуцированных - ОДНАКО, близкое по значению к НО. Смысл-то оставался тот же: одиноко, т. е. противопоставленно всем остальным.

Др.-рус. ОДЬНАКО развивалось параллельно слову ОДИНАКО (чередование и/ь) "тем не менее, несмотря на" (ст.-слав. ѥдинако -"однако, "всё-таки""). Это застывшая краткая форма ср. рода прилагательного ОДИНАКЫИ -"единодушный" - ОДИНАКЪ от ОДИНЪ. Прилагательное стало употребляться в роли  существительного (как вдовая-вдова). В старослав. было сущ. единакъ - инок, монах, т. е. одинокий, не имеющий семьи. От него уже прилагательное одинаковыи-одинаковый (такой же, равный, один и тот же).

В современном ОДНАКО они слились в одну форму. Так что всё и сводится к слову ОДИН, в нём тоже есть значение "обособленный", "противопоставленный".

Comment: И всё сводится к ЕДИНЫЙ. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз., где оно является местоименной формой общеслав. *jedinъ, сложения ограничительной частицы jedъ (см. едва) и числит. inъ "один" (см. иной). Единый буквально — "один-единственный".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.